# Image upload fails with "imgur is rejecting the request"

Tags: bug, imgur

I'm trying to upload an image, which is not uploading I get the response as

**`Failed to upload image; imgur is rejecting the request |`**

[Screenshot-Shared from my personal Onedrive](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsEgl90kVfyygf02kx1yXcHqL_mJHA)

Comment: Right now noticed the same...

Comment: can you share a screenshot of the error? ..... :p

Comment: @TemaniAfif updated my question

Comment: Old, related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291609/intermittent-failed-to-upload-image-imgur-is-rejecting-the-request

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [Unable to upload an image, “An error occurred at imgur”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313725/351462)

Comment: It's [working now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313753/282094).