# Is i.stack.imgur.com down?

Tags: support, bug, images, image-upload, imgur

When trying to access https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuTLg.png (or any other image link to this site) my browser (Chrome) is saying:

> i.stack.imgur.com redirected you too many times.

Is this something on my end?

---

It looks like Imgur may have had another event 11 hours ago: *[Image upload fails with "imgur is rejecting the request"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372133/image-upload-fails-with-imgur-is-rejecting-the-request)*

Comment: Can not reproduce in Chrome Version 68.0.3440.84. seeing a screenshot of a Java Control Panel on what looks to be a Mac OS

Comment: You are not the only one, it has been wonky all day.

Comment: I am seeing the same thing. Latest Chrome version on latest macOS.

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Chrome 68.0.3440.84, Edge 18.17713, or Firefox 63.0a1 on Windows 10 17713.1002

Comment: On MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313790

Comment: I'm having the same thing here. `curl -I https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEDbA.png` issues a 301 `location: http://i.stack.imgur.com/lEDbA.png`, which keeps redirecting to itself until a redirect loop is detected. I'm in Australia currently, for the record, in case it's a localized issue.

Comment: @Pang which has been marked a Dupe of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313779/is-stack-imgur-currently-down   Also experiencing this issue in New Zealand

Comment: It is still happening (New York State).

Comment: Still Happening for me, not resolved. I am in Delhi India

Comment: This seems to be location related. Currently broken here in South Korea, works from TOR circuit beginning in France.

Comment: Works for me in Sweden.

Comment: Appears to be broken in the UK.

Comment: It worked on my cell phone (which 'localized' to somewhere random in Texas), but not when I got to work in central Colorado. If it's location related, it's very localized.

Comment: Appears to be occuring for me as well on my work PC, and home PCs. Also on my phone when connected to the work and home networks, as well as a couple of public networks. The 4G on my phone, however, does not have the issue. Appears to, possibly, be provider specific. Both public and the home provider were BT. Believe work is Zen. Phone 4G is O2. If BT didn't give it away, I'm based in the UK

Comment: Just loaded the pic without issues using the latest Firefox for Android 6.

Comment: It appears to be broken in Italy, too

Comment: Seems to always be having issues, if you ask me...

Answer (score 5):

This has been asked a number of times on meta SE. The one with an "Answer": [Failed to upload an image, "An error occurred at imgur"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313725/failed-to-upload-an-image-an-error-occurred-at-imgur)

In this particular discussion "Rob" (a person from SE) says that the problem is with an outside service (imgur) and that SE is "encouraging" the service to fix the problem as quickly as possible.

Comment: I am getting same loading error for old and new questions and answers which were working earlier. Those include question & answers from various users. Issue still exists. I am in Delhi, India

Comment: @Erik Well, I would have marked as duplicate if the site would allow that between the two "metas". But apparently not...

Comment: As per [What is the recommended course of action for cross-meta duplicates?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317947/7296893), we should just have a separate discussion here. Not really an ideal situation, though.

Comment: @Erik Not in this kind of situation, no. For many things, of course, that would be better. But a technical problem affecting the entire site doesn't need to be discussed (and especially replied to) "everywhere". But I suppose if it makes people better to say "me, too" then it at least spreads the comments around...