# Not able to see embedded image in new or old Question or Answer since today

Tags: support, bug, images, image-upload, imgur

Since today I am not able to see any embedded image in any old question or answer. I tried to check for other user's question with image, it is same there too. I try to edit one question of user with not enough reputation to add image and try to add image from link but not possible. All images exists earlier and are path generated by uploading image to Stack Overflow on  **stack.imgur.com**. I have tried on two different versions of Chrome and Internet Explorer too. I am not sure what is wrong.

Anyone else facing same?

Screenshot of issue:

[image: Screenshot of issue]

---

**EDIT**

---

There are many such supported questions but all ignored without any investigation, seems issue faced by some people and some are not facing this issue:

[Is stack.imgur currently down?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313779/is-stack-imgur-currently-down)

[Is i.stack.imgur.com down?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372187/is-i-stack-imgur-com-down)

[i.stack.imgur seems to be down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313790/i-stack-imgur-seems-to-be-down)

[Is stack.imgur currently down?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313779/is-stack-imgur-currently-down)

**No Question has accepted answer** and issue exists.

Comment: Its working for me check it here [test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zy9Qq.jpg)

Comment: @NileshRathod not working for me even that link, Are you able to see attached image in question itself?

Comment: @PranavSingh strange its working in my  pc check the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5ax6.png)

Comment: Strange enough, any image on i.stack.imgur.com is not working for me. which region you are working?

Comment: You know where the image in this question is hosted? You guessed it.

Comment: @PranavSingh from gujrat

Comment: @cerbus all answers even old with links on http://i.stack.imgur.com are also not working

Comment: This question is more close to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313725/failed-to-upload-an-image-an-error-occurred-at-imgur but issue seems replicating for many people at different geographies yet

Comment: @PranavSingh That one is about uploading images to imgur and this one about viewing them. Completely different problems that might have the same source. (ps. It's working in the Netherlands)

Comment: I am not able to see added image in answer to that question even. @AndréKool BTW my Question is marked as duplicate for that Question

Comment: @AndréKool Please look it is duplicate of question that is answered saying it is duplicate of another question which is again not related any many user reported as replicating that issue. Closing this question is totally fine but issue is not resolved.

Comment: I'm having the same problem here. I thought it was my network, but my phone also can't view the images (on the 4G or an entirely different network).

Comment: The linked thread also shows that the problem is to do with uploading, that isn't the issue. The problem is viewing them. In FireFox you, the error is: `The page isn’t redirecting properly`. In Edge it is `Hmmm... cannot reach this page` and IE () it's `Cannot reach this page`. Clearly there is an issue.

Comment: I also love the irony of @NileshRathod 's comment. Those of us that can't access the images, we can't see his image, however, for those that can, they can. Therefore his comment proves his point for both sides. 

Comment: It's really not useful to have multiple open questions about the same issue. Therefor I voted to leave this one closed.

Comment: This is a duplicate. On meta the duplicate target doesn't have to be answered. It's a bug, the site is aware of it and working on it. Duplicating questions about it are not going to get it fixed more quickly sorry.